# What is dependency in package.json - nodejs

Tags: node.js, package, npm

In my node projcet I build independent modules in to folder with main.js as entry point and locate helpers for that module in the same folder as different files.

```
Ex:
Aggregator:
     |___package.json
     |___main.js
     |___node_modules
         |_____helper1.js
         |_____helper2.js
```

Hence node will resolve all my helpers' dependency for modules [Ex: Aggregator] from local `node_modules` folder. Reason for above structure is, I don't need to care about the path on `require`

I use package.json to specify that entry point is main.js incase `require` is for Aggregator

```
Ex:
//Sample.js
require('Aggregator'); // Resolves to Aggregator/main.js
```

Ex:
package.json of Aggregator module

```
  {
        "name": "Aggregator"
      , "description": "Returns Aggregates"
      , "keywords": ["aggregate"]
      , "author": "Tamil"
      , "contributors": []
      , "dependencies": {
            "redis": "0.6.7"
        }
      , "lib"           : "."
      , "main"          : "./main.js"
      , "version"       : "1.0"
    }
```

Here what is the dependency column for? I referred [this](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/package-dependencies-done-right) link. My code seems to work even if I specify version of redis as 10000 without any warning. I tried deleting my redis module out of project to test whether node picks it up and resolves the dependency but it didn't. When to use that dependency attribute in package.json? Is it just a note for future reference?

**npm version 1.1.0-beta-4 ;
node version v0.6.6**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `dependencies` value is used to specify any other modules that a given module (represented by the `package.json`) requires to work.  When you run `npm install` from the root folder of a given module, it will install any modules listed in that `dependencies` object.

If you didn't get any errors with `redis: 10000` listed in there, my guess is that you never ran `npm install`, and therefore it never even tried to install redis. Note that if your code is working fine without having run `npm install`, most likely your code doesn't even need redis in the first place, and that entry should be removed from the `dependencies` object.

While not every entry in the `package.json` is essential to understand for day-to-day development, a working knowledge of `dependencies` is essential.  I would recommend reading through the [dependencies section on the npm website](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies).

Comment: So, is it unnecessary or not advisable to use package.json for local modules we build? Because If I run `npm install` in my project folder it throws me error, as they are really not packages found anywhere but just my local code and hence dependency is not resolved. I mean Aggregator is not a package but module built by me which has dependencies to redis. In that case how would resolve them?

Comment: It's still advisable to use a `package.json` for published dependencies of a locally developed module. However, if you need to use a locally developed module within *another* locally developed module, you have a couple options, the best of which is usually to use `npm link`. With `npm link`, you go into the root folder of *ModuleA*, and simply type `npm link`. Then from the root folder of *ModuleB*, type `npm link module-a-name`. Then from anywhere with *ModuleB* you can simply `require('module-a-name')`, like you would if it had been installed within `node_modules` (even though it's not).

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies are nothing but it is a third party package or we can say that modules installed using npm.
EX.

```
{
      "name": "abc",
       "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
       "main": "app.js",
     "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "npm",
    "npm@latest",
    "-gnpm",
    "npm@latest",
    "-gnpm",
    "npm@latest",
    "-g"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",   //THIS IS THIRD PARTY PACKAGE/MODULES 
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "nano": "^8.2.2"
  }
}
```