# heroku error while deploying node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app to heroku. Everything was working fine until now.... I don't know what I've done, but everytime I start the process I'm getting this error,

```
2012-12-17T14:36:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-12-17T14:36:42+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-12-17T14:36:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-12-17T14:36:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-12-17T14:36:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-12-17T14:36:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-12-17T14:36:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './proto'
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:378:17)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:14:13)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2012-12-17T14:36:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

Anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with mongoose version

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm I think that you are trying to use your own file, with this sentence:

```
require('./proto');
```

Do you have your proto.js file in the same directory? It seems to be that it cant find that module.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have "proto" in your package.json, this error happend because it cant find a dependency

package.json ex:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "proto": "*"
  }
}
```

check this:
[What is dependency in package.json - nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620583/what-is-dependency-in-package-json-nodejs)

Comment: I know that this is because it cannot find it. But this should not be the problem. It's a dependency because connect uses, express is on the package.json.... so it shouldn't be this.