# NodeJS command "npm install -g" is not working?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run simple express server in node. But when I install the dependencies it's giving me error that node "Cannot find express".

here is console logs

```
asus@DESKTOP-PL2TIDL MINGW64 /f/nitishWorkspace/nitishGitRepo/chatApp (master)
$ npm install -g express
express@4.14.0 C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express
├── array-flatten@1.1.1
├── escape-html@1.0.3
├── encodeurl@1.0.1
├── content-type@1.0.2
├── range-parser@1.2.0
├── fresh@0.3.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── etag@1.7.0
├── content-disposition@0.5.1
├── vary@1.1.0
├── serve-static@1.11.1
├── methods@1.1.2
├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
├── parseurl@1.3.1
├── cookie@0.3.1
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── depd@1.1.0
├── qs@6.2.0
├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)
├── finalhandler@0.5.0 (unpipe@1.0.0, statuses@1.3.0)
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── proxy-addr@1.1.2 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@1.1.1)
├── accepts@1.3.3 (negotiator@0.6.1, mime-types@2.1.11)
├── type-is@1.6.13 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.11)
└── send@0.14.1 (destroy@1.0.4, statuses@1.3.0, ms@0.7.1, mime@1.3.4, http-errors@1.5.0)

asus@DESKTOP-PL2TIDL MINGW64 /f/nitishWorkspace/nitishGitRepo/chatApp (master)
$ node server.js
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\nitishWorkspace\nitishGitRepo\chatApp\server.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

I think the problem lies in these lines

```
express@4.14.0 C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express
```

and

```
asus@DESKTOP-PL2TIDL MINGW64 /f/nitishWorkspace/nitishGitRepo/chatApp (master)
```

As you can notice the path is different here. I think that the dependencies are getting install in different directory and node is not able to access that.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Maybe install express in your app directory. Global modules are used only if you want to run them from command line. So just run npm i express and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem: The problem is with the PATH. The node is not able to find this path `express@4.14.0 C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express` 
so you can check out this --> [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700286/2326587).

I am not merging the questions because the issue here is different but the solution is same.

Hope this solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing express into your dependencies inside your package.json

`npm install --save express`

If you do not have a package.json you can create one using the following command from within the root of your project.

`npm init -y`

This command creates a package.json in your root directory using all the default values.

**note**

If you use:

`npm init`

You will be asked a series of questions, but you can set those up later by editing your package.json

[See the docs here for more information about package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

[For more information about setting up dependencies see this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620583/what-is-dependency-in-package-json-nodejs)

**edit addressing comment**

[Regarding using globally installed dependencies see this SO q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480549/install-dependencies-globally-and-locally-using-package-json)

Comment: this again creates a local copy of dependencies in node_modules folder, I really don't want to do that. I just want to install them globally.

Answer (score 0):

You should install express `locally`.. do `npm install express` in your chat app...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to install the ExpressJS CLI generator, if this is the case then run this command

`npm install express-generator -g`

And then you can type

`express my_app`

To create a folder with the whole structure inside. Then go inside the created folder:

`cd my_app`

and type: `nam install`, to install all the dependencies and express itself.